# mailTo : How to open in new tab without tab being empty

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I got a web form on a state government intranet site. It is a simple webform.
     On some of the documents that linkbuttons populate a iframe I will send a email to a manager that the document will be printed. I have a new tab open, this is to keep the page still current, but the tab is empty and says "navigation canceled". The manager would like tab to open to a simple webpage that has a reminder to hit the send button.  I cannot find out how to get the tab populated by my alert page. This c# code that is calling javascript to have a new tab open.

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open('" + mailto + "','_blank')", true);
```

My page is titled HTML1.html and is in the same directory as my .aspx page. I cannot find documentation to do this, not sure it is even possible. Can the above function do what i want, and if not is there a way to have the email open on the current page without the page reloading and losing all current information?

Comment: of course this is possible.. do search for the following for examples 
`C# stackoverflow RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "popup", "window.open(`

Comment: @MethodMan. I have , but have not seen any examples that use Mailto and opening a new tab that is not blank.